# Nios II system generated by Qsys looks awful (All pin are at one side). Can we make it look better?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus-ii, quartus, nios-ii

I have tried Quartus 16.0 and 14.1.
Both of them generate Nios II system that looks very awful as shown in the figure below.

[image: Nios II system generated by Qsys using Quartus 14.1 (I have tried 16.0 but the same)]

Is there any way to make it look better like the previous version as shown below.

[image: Old style Nios II system]

Comment: Nope. Or at least, not in a way that isn't overwritten each time you regenerate it.

Comment: Though if you ask me, if you want to make it look nicer, instantiate it in a Verilog file not a schematic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem now. I can make it look better by adding the .vhd file of the nios system into the project. Right click on it and choose "create symbol file for current file". It looks nice now.

[image]